# My delete function | method can not delete in Laravel Vuejs

Tags: php, json, laravel, vue.js

This is why i can't delete by ID, even the code is inactive at id, its a JS file.
[image: This is why i can't delete by ID, even the code is inactive at id]

This is my delete function in controller

```
> public function destroy(Estate $estates)
>     {
>         if ($estates->delete()) {
>             return response()->json([
>                 'message' => 'Estate deleted successfully',
>                 'status_code' => 200
>             ], 200);
>         } else {
>             return response()->json([
>                 'message' => 'Can not delete, Some error occured, please try again later',
>                 'status_code' => 500
>             ], 500);
>         }
>     }
```

Below is my Vue method to initiate the delete method
first is my button
second is my delete method

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" v-on:click="deleteEstate(estate)"> <span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span></button>
   
>        deleteEstate: async function(estate) {
>         if (!window.confirm('Are You sure you want to delete this Estate Record!')) {
>            return;
>         }
> 
>         try {
>             await estateService.deleteEstate(estate.id);
> 
>             this.estate = this.estate.filter(obj => {
>               return obj.id != estate.id;
>             });
>         } catch (error) {
>           
>         }
>       }
```

this is my result on delete, need some help!
[image: this is my result on delete, need some help]

Comment: You might have to do a bit of troubleshooting. Try `Log::info("Deleting ".$estates->id);` at the top of your destroy function, and check your log file (`/storage/logs`) to make sure it's got the correct ID. Surround the delete in a try/catch block and see if there's an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `deleteEstate()` you're using single quotes '' but `${}` operator needs the backquote `` in order to work. Try changing it.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending /estate/{id} to your backend. You should wrap the string in backticks `.